asgardeo - api call
I use the free version of Asgardeo and would like to authenticate the users of my applications by centralizing the login and logout procedures. The idea would be to have a microservice which, upon receiving the user/password pair from the various clients, would then carry out the authentication on Asgardeo. Is there a way to do this?

You can integrate Asgardeo with your applications by using the SDKs.
Refer: https://wso2.com/asgardeo/docs/integrations/
